# KendoUI chart - Fix pie chart width and not chartArea to avoid cutting part of the legends

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I use the chartarea of the Kendochart, it defines the size of the outer area and as result the legend of the chart doesn't show fully.
How can we set a fix size only for the pie chart and not the are that contains both the legend and the chart?

tried chartarea, css k-chart sizing or even .k-chart svn, padding, css width

1)

```
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
    chartArea: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    },
    ....
```

this changes the area that also contains the legends and not only the chart

2)

```
     <style>
        .k-chart {
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
        }
    </style>
```

this resizes the area too

3)

```
    seriesDefaults: {
    labels: {
    visible: false,
    background: "transparent",
    template: "#= category #: #= value#"
    },
    padding: 50
        },
```

also tried using padding to seriesDeaults. This makes the charts smaller still when I have two same width divs with charts with different legends, their size is not the same. I need my charts to have the exact same size and position in the chartArea.

fix width of pie chart only

Comment: Can you post a picture of your charts?

Comment: @Kevin they are just four pie charts one next to another.
First div contains:
First one (main) bigger, second smaller (secondary)
under those charts (position: "bottom"), it's legends labels

Second div contains:
First one (main) bigger, second smaller (secondary)
under those charts (position: "bottom"), it's legends labels

And of course I've also tried having all those in 4 different divs.

The question is: is it possible to set a specific width ONLY for the pie chart and not the chartArea which also contains the legends?